# Filling missing values in Snowpark: Input value type doesn't match the target column data type

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fill missing values in snowpark by using the following,

`df = df.na.fill(0)`

It replaces missing values for some columns but skips many others, giving the following error,

`Input value type doesn't match the target column data type, this replacement was skipped. Column Name: "MEDIAN_AQI", Type: DecimalType(38, 12), Input Value: 0, Type: <class 'int'>`

I have tried the following as well,

`df = df.na.fill(0.0)`

It still gives the same error. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Decimal` column will not accept integer values or float values, only [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) values. Try this:

```
from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType, DecimalType, StructField, StructType
from decimal import Decimal

schema = StructType([StructField('a', IntegerType()), StructField('b', DecimalType(38, 12))])

df = session.create_dataframe([[1, None],[None, 4.5]], schema)

df.show()

df.na.fill({'a': 0, 'b': Decimal(0)}).show()
```

It should return the following:

```
-------------------------
|"A"   |"B"             |
-------------------------
|1     |NULL            |
|NULL  |4.500000000000  |
-------------------------

------------------------
|"A"  |"B"             |
------------------------
|1    |0E-12           |
|0    |4.500000000000  |
------------------------
```

As [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.6.1/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.fillna) says, you can also fix the problem by using a `FloatType` or `DoubleType` column instead of a `DecimalType` column, because integers can be used in those cases:

> **Note**
>
> If the type of a given `value` in value doesn’t match the column data
> type (e.g. a `float` for [`StringType`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.6.1/api/snowflake.snowpark.types.StringType.html#snowflake.snowpark.types.StringType) column), this replacement
> will be skipped in this column. Especially,
>
> - `int` can be filled in a column with [`FloatType`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.6.1/api/snowflake.snowpark.types.FloatType.html#snowflake.snowpark.types.FloatType) or [`DoubleType`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.6.1/api/snowflake.snowpark.types.DoubleType.html#snowflake.snowpark.types.DoubleType), but `float` cannot filled in a column with
>   [`IntegerType`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.6.1/api/snowflake.snowpark.types.IntegerType.html#snowflake.snowpark.types.IntegerType) or [`LongType`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.6.1/api/snowflake.snowpark.types.LongType.html#snowflake.snowpark.types.LongType).